# Unexpected value returned from getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript

With these styles, if I increase the width, the element  grows from the left side. Which means that getBoundingClientRect().right on that element should have the same value after I adjusted the width.

```
top: 0px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
right: 400px;
```

But it's not the same when I use javascript to increase the width. Why not?

I increase the width when mouse moves over the element like this:

```
console.log(elm.getBoundingClientRect().right);
elm.style.width = parseInt(elm.style.width) + clientX - event.clientX + "px";
```

And the output is different every time.

Comment: You have to show a [mcve] without that it is not possible to tell.

Comment: @t.niese https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-pine-z8phx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark <-- Here you have the example. It starts with a default "left" value (200px), then before the width increases, "left" gets set to "initial" and "right" gets set to the current position. So now when we increase the width it grows from the left side. This doesn't work here, but it should. The solution was to change the values of left/right in a different eventlistener and change the width in another, but that shouldn't be necessary and I dont understand why it doesn't work this way

Comment: The value for `right` says the same for me as long as the window is not resized.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everytime when the width/height increases clientRect show different values for left, right, top, bottom. For example if we increase the width and the div only grows on the right side, the value of clientRect.left should be unchanged. But after the increase clientRect.left sometimes have a different value. There can be a slight difference in the decimal/fractional part of the value.

So now I know that

Answer (score -1):

> Which means that getBoundingClientRect().right on that element should have the same value after I adjusted the width.

That's incorrect. The `right` property is a *coordinate* representing the rightmost boundary of your element. If you increase its width, its position relative to the right will decrease (read: the element will become "closer" to the right edge of the viewport).

It's vice versa: increasing the width doesn't affect the `left` property. Element's position does (like margin or absolute coordinates).

Comment: No what you're saying is not correct or you don't understand the question. Beucase if you check the value of getBoundingClientRect().right BEFORE you increase the width manually from dev tools, it will be the same value as after you increased the width. It grows from left, the right side has the same position x

Comment: The question is why the value becomes different when you do the same thing with js instead of manually in dev tools